# Error <name> expected near "if"

Tags: lua

Hi this is my first lua code but I get a error pls fix it thx in advanced if you do get this working. I have a feeling its a small thing I'm missing.

```
class 'Autochat'

TalkTimer = Timer()
local TalkDelay = 1 -- in minutes
local active = 1

function 
    if active = 0 then
        return
    end

    if active ~= "0" then
        if(TalkTimer:GetSeconds() > (60 * timeDelay)) then
            Chat:Broadcast("Hi the admin is offline.", Colors(0, 255, 0))
            TalkTimer:Restart()
        end
    end
end
Autochat = Autochat()
```

Comment: See [The Complete Syntax of Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#9). It might not be easy to learn it this way but it's a useful reference for when you get stuck or want to reveiw.

Answer (score 4):

The function is missing a name. Lua reads to the next line looking for the function's name and gets confused when it finds an `if` statement.

Also, the first if statement should be `if active == 0 then` because `==` is the comparison operator.

Comment: also the `if active ~= "0"` should be `if active ~= 0` since `active` is a number, and the `timeDelay` should probably be replaced by `TalkDelay`